# Could not parse the remainder: '((records_list.1.key.5)' from '((records_list.1.key.5)'

Tags: python, django

Obligatory "I am new to Django" here...

In my views I am creating a list, called records_list. Inside that list, I have another list in the position [0] and a dictionary in the position [1], as follows:

```
records_list = list()
list_one = Bet.objects.order_by('-game_date')
list_two = {}
```

Inside the "list_two", that is my dictionary, I have a key that is a date "April 2016", for ex, and a value that is a tuple:

```
list_two[aux_month_year] = (aux_wins, aux_losses, aux_voids, s_rate, i_rate, profit)
```

So I return this to my html:

```
records_list.append(list_one)
records_list.append(list_two)
return records_list
```

In the html, I want to create a table, and I start by checking if my profit is positive or not:

```
{% if records_list %}
                <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Wins</th>
                        <th>Losses</th>
                        <th>Void</th>
                        <th>Success Rate</th>
                        <th>Return on Investment</th>
                        <th>Profit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {% for key in records_list.1 %}

                    {% if ((records_list.1.key.5) > 0) %}
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>{{ key }}</td>
                            <td>{{ records_list.1.key.0 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ records_list.1.key.1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ records_list.1.key.2 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ records_list.1.key.3 }}%</td>
                            <td>{{ records_list.1.key.4 }}%</td>
                            <td>{{ records_list.1.key.5 }}</td>

                        </tr>
```

However, I am getting the following syntax error here:

```
{% if ((records_list.1.key.5) > 0) %}
```

Error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '((records_list.1.key.5)' from '((records_list.1.key.5)'
```

If someone could help me and point me to the right direction I would appreciate!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if tag does not support parentheses. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators):

> Use of actual parentheses in the if tag is invalid syntax. If you need them to indicate precedence, you should use nested if tags.

In your case, the parentheses are not required, so just remove them:

```
{% if records_list.1.key.5 > 0 %}
```